# Is this homebrew Necromancer class balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review, necromancy

Is [this necromancer class](https://www.gmbinder.com/share/-LE63w7F2ikQ4170d0Da/-LXC48MwNx9kay5nrDPp) balanced, compared to a warlock or cleric? One of my players would like to use it.

The goal is for it to be roughly balanced compared to a cleric, since that’s what I believe it to be most similar to. The spell list has both healing and offense, but I think it has less utility, and is slightly worse at healing and offense. Therefore, the subclasses should be stronger - I don’t know how much stronger. Overall, I suspect that this class is slightly weaker due to the lack of a good spell list, but I’m not sure.

It should hold thematically to the idea of someone who controls life and death. I think most of the features do that already.

I see that the Creed of the Departed is difficult or impossible, to analyze, since it depends on exactly what monsters the DM sends at the party. If it has potential to be much stronger or weaker than the other subclasses, please explain why, but you don’t have to touch on it at all. I also notice that a player can drain all the undead’s health with Vitality Shift, then give it back at half price, but that’s not too powerful - spending two uses of Vitality Shift to gain no more than a few dozen HP.

I’m curious how the Creed of the Siphon compares to hexblade warlocks and combat-focused clerics, since it has both full casting and combat abilities. I see that it’s vulnerable to a bag-of-rats trick, stabbing rats to regain health or using Chill Touch - I want to know how it measures up to those classes without that.

I believe that the Creed of the Tome has mostly balanced abilities, a few abilities that are odd (Twinned Fate, Seance) and a few that are underpowered for their level (Galerider, Religious Familiarity) - I want to know if there’s something big that I’m not noticing.

If you have any suggestions for alterations that make this class better, either in theme or in power, feel free to say them! I don’t currently have a good idea for how to make sure the Creed of the Departed is balanced, but I’d love to have one.

Comment: I know this is asking a lot, but it would be best if you could reproduce the class text here (assuming you’re allowed to do so), so that if the link to it goes down, the question is still preserved here.

Comment: Don't know about balanced, but the level 20 feature for siphon is off the page

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I could try that. It would be about 18 pages, so I'm slightly hesitant to do so.
I don't know how to set up tables, though. Could you link something that explains it? It's probably somewhere I should have noticed, but didn't.

Comment: @Phoenices Markdown tables are explained [here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10075/62294), a totally non-obvious location, I’m not surprised you weren’t sure where to look lol.

Comment: You can also reduce the text transferred over by only including the feature names and descriptions and none of the lore descriptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Summary

**A *Necromancer* of the *Creed of Tomes* is balanced, any other is over-powered.**

#### Base Class: Balanced

The base class is very similar to a *Bard*: it has the same number of Spells known, for example.

It has only one more Cantrip, at the cost of a lower hit die (d6).

Its *Vitality Shift* is interesting. The fact that it can transfer up to 400 Hit Points at level 20 may be scary, but on its own this feature is not a problem due to the limited number of uses per day -- up to 5 -- and the fact that it is a *transfer*: any Hit Point taken from another must still be healed, in the end.

There are a few potential for abuses. A horde of followers is the obvious one, but the DM should be able to curtail that quickly.

*Eternal Youth* is on the powerful side. Few classes gain Proficiency in a second major Saving Throw. If the character also takes the Resilient feat for Dexterity, this leads them to covering all 3 major ones, and therefore being a bit of a pain to deal with. It comes online at level 18, though, when the character already has access to 9th level spells...

#### Creed of the Departed: Overpowered

The *Undead Minion* feature is hard to judge, due to its open ended nature, although there are good limits in place:

1. The Necromancer must expand its Hit Dice to create and maintain a creature.
2. The number of Hit Points of the creature is rather limited: 40 + 1d6 at level 20.
3. The abilities of the creatures are trimmed down, with penalties and restrictions.

Even the *Conduit Walker* feature is clearly copied from the *Find Familiar* Spell: same range, same use of *Reaction*.

The *Sheperd's Resolve* lifts the speed penalty, and adds another 1d6 of Hit Points to the *Undead Minion*. Both are minor gains.

The *Animator Style* is concerning, or at least 2 out of 3 options are:

- *Adept Awakener* seems mild enough, just a few bonuses here and there.
- *Giant Rouser* causes some concerns. Raising a *Huge* creature seems likely to open up some shenanigans, and the extra +5 to the CR of creatures one can raise doesn't help.
- *Undead Magnate* also causes some concerns, in the Action Economy sense. The ability to have up to *6* creatures under the player's control is *much* more potent than having 1 creature with 2 attacks, and the reduction in Hit Points doesn't make up for it.

*Still Life* is a ribbon; little enough mechanical effect.

And *Legendary Animator* causes concern again, building upon *Animator Style*: 6 Huge Creatures will cause a lot of mayhem...

#### Creed of the Siphon: Overpowered

*Sycophant* is problematic. There is no other feature in the game which does not place a limit on the amount of Hit Points one can heal. For example, the Champion's capstone ability only heals them up to 50% of their Hit Points. Also, in combination with *Vitality Shift* it allows regenerating a significant portion of the party Hit Point pool.

*Learned Siphoner* is also problematic. First of all *Necrotic* is not as oft resisted as non-magical damage, or even *Fire* and *Cold*, so the ability to have a *Fireball* deal *Necrotic* damage is problematic in and out of itself. Worse, though, is that it compounds with *Sycophant*: 1/3 of the newly dealt damage heals the *Necromancer* after all...

The sub-features of *Learned Siphoner* are mixed:

- *Essence Weaver* is overpowered: the extra damage doesn't matter, the problem is the healing. A limit of *Sycophant* + *Vitality Shift* is the number of uses of *Vitality Shift*: *Essence Weaver* does away with this limit, giving the entire party infinite health.
- *Vigor Thief* is alright: once per Long Rest, so it's fine if it's a bit powerful.

*Ascetic Dominion* offers cheap resurrection. By level 10 some forms of resurrection are available already, and the level of exhaustion suffered prevents really jumping back into the fray. I could foresee mass-resurrection abuse: resurrecting an entire village, 1 Hit Point per villager. Whether that can really be exploited is less clear, however.

*Everlasting* is one of many abilities to thwart death available to players; once per Long Rest is definitely fine.

*Blood Funnel* is concerning due to its ability to steal Hit Points from foes; but given *Sycophant* it doesn't add much...

*Note: I couldn't see all the text for Blood Funnel, due to formatting issues and apparently a "cut" copy/paste; I may have missed something.*

#### Creed of Tomes: Balanced

*Initiate of the Tome* is fine. The Refined Spell is the only powerful feature, and it's a once per Long Rest one.

*Arcane Shift* is once again a transfer, so none too problematic, especially given the 1 Spell Slot per shift combined with the limited number of possible shifts.

*Evercasting* is a good capstone. It should not kick in too often, due to the (cumulated) CR 10 requirement, and its limitation to lower-level Spell Slots limits abuse: Action Economy dictates that again powerful foes, the higher-level Spell Slots will be the most necessary.

The *Augur's Acumen* really depends on the Acumen. Of interest, there is no possibility to switch a known Acumen for another, hence it is not possible to end up with all high-level Acumen and no low-level one.

I noted 2 interesting Acumen, which I think could be accidentally construed as more powerful than they are:

- *Channeler*: This is essentially Blindsight to 10 ft. The limited range limits its power, fortunately.
- *Gale Rider*: Abilities to ignore difficult terrain and walk across water (or lava) are rare, and spells have limited uses. The character has access to 7th level spells at this level, though, so can use *Fly* and similar for the occasional obstacle.

Overall, I find *Augur's Acumen* fairly balanced.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't see how a necroball is an issue - Learned Siphoner only applies to Necromancer spells. I'll agree that, say, sickening radiance could give ridiculous healing, though. 
What do you think of the spell list's power level? It doesn't look very strong to me, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Phoenices: You are correct that Fireball may have been a poor example here, though there are some ways to add spells to a spell-list already (_Magic Initiate_ comes to mind) and more may appear as more content is added. I am more worried about weapon attacks, to a degree, though, since they provide "infinite" source of damage, and therefore "infinite" source of healing -- though I do note that for a sub-class supposed to hit with a weapon, the lack of Extra Attack is perplexing. I agree that the spell list is maybe on the light side -- few spells -- but most are thematic which is nice.

Comment: If Siphoner played around with temporary HP instead of actual healing, I'd be a lot less worried about it.

Comment: If you choose undead magnate, the health of your undead minions goes *way* down, because it’s only two hit dice (2d6+2*constitution modifier), which is low enough that one fireball will wipe out all of your minions (unless you do some shenanigans to get a ridiculously high constitution, such as tomes), so I don’t think it’s a problem.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica: They are indeed fragile, however they can hit really hard, also known as the Glass Cannon. This does reward clever play -- getting the drop on the enemy, or good tactical position -- but it does mean that in the hands of even an average player they can do a _lot_ of damage. Imagine a horde of 6 creatures with _Hold Person_ ability in an ambush. Or a horde of 6 Stone Giants, equidistantly spread on a 60 ft. circle around a group, all throwing rocks. They'll pile  on a lot of damage before their target escapes or drops them.

Comment: @MatthieuM. then they’re essentially an expendable resource, does a lot of damage but can only be used once (unless the enemy has no ranged AoE attacks), so it can be compared to an extra spell slot. (Except it’s way harder to set up. Good luck finding 6 Stone Giant corpses). Also, ambushing people is already pretty broken in 5e.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica: Even if the enemy has ranged AoE, the creatures are under control within _1 mile_. You can spread them out so that no 2 of them fit within a fireball, forcing the enemy to go after them 1 at a time. You can protect them too: Temporary HPs, Protection from Elements, Cover, etc... Wizards are brittle, and they don't die all the time either.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I can’t believe I forgot about that. In that case, yeah, that’s pretty OP.

Answer (score 3):

### Rituals are an issue.

Others have already done a much better job of analyzing the class as a whole, but I want to point out one sneaky little problem that popped out to me. That there's a bit of missing text in the Rituals class feature. It may be an oversight, but it feels like it's trying to sneak something past the DM.

For reference, here's the Ritual feature for the Bard, Cleric, and Wizard:

> You can cast *any bard spell you know* as a ritual if that spell has the ritual tag.

> You can cast a cleric spell as a ritual if that spell has the ritual tag and *you have the spell prepared*.

> You can cast a wizard spell as a ritual if that spell has the ritual tag and *you have the spell in your spellbook*. You don't need to have the spell prepared.

Now compare to the Necromancer:

> You can cast *any necromancer spell* as a ritual if that spell has the ritual tag.

Notice what's missing? All the official classes require that, to use a ritual, you have to know or prepare the spell in question (or have it written in your spellbook, which is basically the same as knowing it for wizards).

The necromancer *technically* gives you access to *any ritual spell on the necromancer list* without having to learn it first. Like I said, maybe this is an oversight; maybe they *meant* to say "any necromancer spell *you know*".  But that isn't what the rule actually says, so it makes me suspicious of the class as a whole.

If you allow this, you'll need to make a clarifying statement that the character can only use rituals they actually have learned; otherwise it's very broken indeed.

Comment: The spell list is small, I wonder how many Ritual spells there are. It may not be that problematic if there's only a handful.

Comment: I never trust balance that's based on a class spell list.  Class spell lists are easily altered at any time.

Comment: Agreed, but that may explain the wording. Carelessness is the most logical explanation, of course, but if intentional I'd expect the author _didn't_ consider spell list alteration.